# Capturar resultado devuelto de mysql utilizando PDO asignando variable INT

Tags: php, pdo

Necesito poder recuperar un registro de la BD y almacenarlo en una variable como valor entero utilizando PDO, no consigo dar con la clave y me aparecere el siguiente error:

```
/*llamo a la función*/
$vNumTicket = ($accessDB->obtenerValor());

/*Entro en la funcion*/   
public function obtenerValor(){

        $sentencia = $this->db->prepare('SELECT MAX(`num_ticket`) FROM `tb_msg`;');
        $sentencia->execute();

        $maximo=0;

        if ($sentencia) {
            $fila = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                              //fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) -->Devuelve Error
            $maximo = ($sentencia->$num_rows === 0) ? 0 :  $fila["maximo"];

           /*He probado otras opciones*/
          //$maximo = $sentencia->$fila["maximo"];
          //$maximo = $fila["maximo"];

        }
        return (int) $maximo;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor necesito ayuda,
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

He dado con la clave con
`fetch_column()`;

```
public function obtenerValor(){

        //Defino los parámetros de salida
        $sentencia = $this->db->prepare('SELECT MAX(`num_ticket`) FROM `tb_msg`;');
        $sentencia->execute();

        if ($sentencia) {
            $fila = $sentencia->fetchColumn();
            echo $fila;
        }
        return ($fila);
```